# Possible to root Archos 79 Platinum

Tags: rooting, tablet

I want to root this device:

[Archos 79 Platinum](http://www.archos.com/se/products/tablets/platinum/archos_79platinum/index.html)

Is it possible, and can someone link me to a guide please?
(I couldn't find a clear cut answer whether it is rootable or not)

Comment: Current generic suggestion: Try [towelroot by geohot](https://towelroot.com/), should work with most devices. Please don't forget to report back whether you succeeded.

Comment: Towelroot only works on latest Android-dist. I tried it and it doesn't work. However, I managed using VROOT. See Answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES!** It is possible to root the **Archos 79 Platinum** using the following methods:

[VROOT-root exe file for use on Windows machines](http://www.mgyun.com/en/getvroot)

And to replace the superuser-app with an English version:

[English Superuser and busybox etc](http://www.w0lfdroid.com/2013/11/How-to-Remove-Replace-VRoot-Chinese-superuser-with-SuperSU.html)

Yoy may also first want to check out the following link to make sure USB works properly (also google on how to enable developer-mode and USB-debugging on Android devices in general):

[Enable Archos USB devices](http://www.archos.com/us/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html)

I just rooted my device, so I know for sure that it works.